# Flux:How to test empty Flux

Tags: java, project-reactor, reactive

Is there a way to use ArgumentCapture for Flux?

I want to mock a service where the input parameters (flux) are created during the process:

```
Flux<A> fluxa = createFluxA();
Flux<B> fluxb = createFluxB()
...
return service.createMono(fluxa,fluxb)
```

My Unit Test:

```
AObject aobject = mock(AObject.class);
when(service.createMono(any(), any()).thenReturn(Mono.just(aobject));

...
StepVerifer...
```

The Unit Test works only if I use the matcher any(). If fluxB should be a empty Flux how can I test this? eq(Flux.empty()) does not work because Flux has no equal function

Thx in advance

Comment: Perhaps a matcher using `hasElements()`?

Comment: how can I user hasElements in the mock?

Comment: the problem with matchers is that `Flux` are lazy, only generating elements / trigerring their source when they are subscribed to. thus there's no way of knowing in advance if a Flux will be empty or not. what are you trying to test exactly with the mock?

Answer (score 2):

To Test empty Flux you can use `verifyComplete()` just after `Subscription`. If Flux has elements then test will fail

```
StepVerifier.create(myflux)
                    .expectSubscription()
                    .verifyComplete();
```

You can also check `expectNextCount(0)`

Comment: `expectNextCount(0)` is better for null values.